# How to use any existing variable value in Spinner selection?

Tags: android

want to use the the value of variable b in spinner selection. See the code .

```
  button.setOnClickListener(
  new Button.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View view) {

      String name = editText.getText().toString();

      if (yes.isChecked()) {
          int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString());

              int l;
              l = 80 ;
              int y ;
              y = l - age ;

              c = y - 7;
              final int z;
              b = 2016 + c;

              editText3.setText((name + " you might die in the year ")+ b + "");

               } else {
                   if (no.isChecked()) {
                       int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString());
                            int c;

                            int l;
                            l = 80;
                            int y;
                            y = l - age;
                            c = y + 10;

                            b = 2016 + c;

                            editText3.setText(name + (" you might die in year ") + b  + "");}}} // this is button code //
```

now comes the spinner code .

```
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int position, long id)
                            {

   final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                      list.add("none,i am healthy");
                      list.add("Diabetes");
                      list.add("cancer");
                      list.add("HIV/AIDS");
                      list.add("Tuberculosis");
                      list.add("Coronary Artery");
                      list.add("respiratory disease");
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
  String disease = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
  spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

  if (disease.equals("Diabetes")) {

       int x = b-5;
       int j = 2016+ x ;
       String name = editText.getText().toString();

       editText3.setText(name + (" you might die in year ") + j  + ""); }

       else if (disease.equals("none,i am healthy")) {
       String name = editText.getText().toString();

                     int x = b + 7 ;
                     int j = 2016 + x  ;
                     editText3.setText(name + ( "you might die in year ") + j + "");


                     }

              };});


              };};
```

this app is executing without an error yet it is not giving me the desired output . How do i use the value of b in spinner ( i have already defined it global)

Comment: *you might die in year*, quite an interesting app this :D

Comment: Can you solve this problem?